# How can I represent this generic type

Tags: java, generics

How can I fix the generic type part to let it represent a Map of Long and Anything implements Collection?

```
Map<Long,  <T implements Collection<Long>>> moc;
```

So that I can do  `moc = new HashMap<Long, Set<Long>>();`

Comment: Use MultiMap for it ? Also you should not have to use generics as collections is the parent for set. for multi map read [this](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: How can I use MultiMap in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you could use

```
Map<Long,  Collection<Long>> moc = new HashMap<>();
```

Which will allow you to add a `Set` like

```
moc.put((long) 1, new HashSet<Long>());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can I do things like
 Map<Long,  <T implements Collection<Long>>> moc;
which will allow me to do
moc = new HashMap<Long, Set<Long>>(); and
moc = new HashMap<Long, List<Long>>();?

Comment: @WeijieWang It won't work in Java, but you have my permission.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
Map<Long, Collection<Long>> moc = new HashMap<Long, Collection<Long>>();
moc.put(new Long(1), new ArrayList<Long>()); //works
moc.put(new Long(2), new TreeSet<Long>()); //works
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can I do things like Map<Long, <T implements Collection<Long>>> moc; which will allow me to do moc = new HashMap<Long, Set<Long>>(); and moc = new HashMap<Long, List<Long>>();?